# backgroundVideo' is defined but never used no-unused-vars (ReactJS)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add background video in react, here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import './Wrapper.css'
import backgroundVideo from './images/background-video.mp4'

const Wrapper = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <video className="wrapper" poster="./images/poster.png" autoPlay>
                <source src="{backgroundVideo}" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Wrapper
```

The problem is that I am getting this error in the console

```
"Line 3:8:  'backgroundVideo' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars"
```

In my VS CODE editor, the 3rd line of the program in which I am importing the video is also faded which means the value is not being used in my program, but I am using the variable backgroundVideo in the src of the source tag.

Comment: You are wrapping src in double quotes. This should fix the issue: <source src={backgroundVideo} type="video/mp4" />

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake :)